# Population Dynamics Part 1

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

So I previously posted a long question consisting of 5 parts but I was advised to break it up into 5 questions. So the first part asks:

If $A$ is a constant matrix, then 
$$
\vec{N}(t+\Delta t)= A\vec{N}(t)
$$ 
is a linear system of constant coefficient first order difference equations. Use the notation $\vec{N_m} \equiv \vec{N}(m\Delta t)$, and hence $\vec{N_{m+1}} = A\vec{N_m}$. Try a solution to this system of difference equations in the form $\vec{N_m}=r^m\vec{C}$, where $\vec{C}$ is a constant vector and where $r$ will be determined. Show that 
$$
(A-rI)\vec{C}=\vec{0},
$$ 
where $I$ is the identity matrix. From the linear algebra, we know that for nontrivial solutions (i.e., $\vec{C} \neq 0$), $r$ can be only certain values called eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, obtained by insisting $A-rI$ has a zero determinant, 
$$
|A-rI|=0.
$$ 
If $A$ is an $n$ x $n$ matrix, then there will be $n$ eigenvalues (call them $r_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$). We assume (for mathematical simplicity) that the eigenvalues of $A$ are all distinct. Corresponding to each eigenvalue $r_i$, there is a vector $\vec{C_i}$ satisfying ($A-r_iI)\vec{C_i}=\vec{0}$, which we call an eigenvector.

---

I think I figured out a solution but I have **NO** idea if it is even remotely correct. So if $$\vec{N_m}=r^m \vec{c}$$ then $$\vec{N_{m+1}}=r^{m+1}\vec{c}$$ and $$\vec{N_{m+1}}=A\vec{N_m}$$
so we can set them equal to each other, multiply by the matrix $I$ and simplify like so:
$$r^{m+1}\vec{c} = AN_m $$
$$r^{m+1}\vec{c} = Ar^m \vec{c}$$
$$r\vec{c} = A \vec{c}$$
$$Ir\vec{c} = IA\vec{c}$$
$$0=\vec{c}(A-Ir)$$

Does that answer the question or no?

Comment: It is not really clear what the question is, since the cited text is more a motivation for the introduction of eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Your interpretation of the text and the left-out steps is correct. Up to the last one. $c$ and $A$ do not commute, $0=(A-rI)\vec c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, If $\vec{x}_{n+1}=A\vec{x}_n$, then $\vec{x}_n = A^n\vec{x}_0$. Of course, computing $A^n$ is "hard", so one thing that can be done is to diagonalize it -- $A=PDP^{-1}(=S\Lambda S^{-1})$ (refer to any standard textbook on linear algebra). This is neat, because then $A^n=(PDP^{-1})^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ and computing $D^n$ is easy since it is a diagonal matrix (of the eigenvalues of $A$).

Of course, this procedure is somewhat more work than necessary -- in general, it motivates the ansatz that you were trying to implement, since if you closely examine $PD^nP^{-1}\vec{x}_0$, you'll see that you can separately consider solutions of the form $\vec{x}_n=r^n \vec{c}$.